# Python windll.SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces throughs error code 6

Tags: python

I have been translating Tcl code that works into python so I know the GUID hex values are correct. Just not sure why WinError() is throwing Code: 6 cause winapi.SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces is returning 0.

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes
import win32file
 
DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE          = 0x00000010
DIGCF_PRESENT                  = 0x00000002
FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED           = 0x40000000
FILE_SHARE_READ                = 0x00000001
FILE_SHARE_WRITE               = 0x00000002
FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER = 0x00000100
FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM     = 0x00001000
GENERIC_READ                   = 0x80000000
GENERIC_WRITE                  = 0x40000000
OPEN_EXISTING                  = 3
WAIT_TIMEOUT                   = 0x00000102
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE           = -1
 
winapi = windll.setupapi
 
 
class GUID(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('Data1', c_ulong),
        ('Data2', c_ushort),
        ('Data3', c_ushort),
        ('Data4', c_ubyte*8),
    ]
    def __str__(self):
        return "{%08x-%04x-%04x-%s-%s}" % (
            self.Data1,
            self.Data2,
            self.Data3,
            ''.join(["%02x" % d for d in self.Data4[:2]]),
            ''.join(["%02x" % d for d in self.Data4[2:]]),
        )
 
 
class SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cbSize', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('InterfaceClassGuid', GUID),
        ('Flags', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('Reserved', POINTER(c_ulong)),
    ]
    def __str__(self):
        self.cbSize = sizeof(self)
        return "InterfaceClassGuid:%s Flags:%s" % (self.InterfaceClassGuid, self.Flags)
 
 
GUID_SPWR_BASE_INTERFACE = GUID(0xa480c318, 0xfd41, 0x4973,
    (c_ubyte*8)(0xa5,0x4a, 0xa8, 0x24, 0x93, 0x11, 0xc7, 0x71))
GUID_SPWR_CHAN_INTERFACE = GUID(0xe1eda58b, 0xf16c, 0x4489, (c_ubyte * 8)(0xa4,0xe9, 0xb4, 0xaa, 0x4f, 0x12, 0xb1, 0x6b))
 
 
hDevInfo = winapi.SetupDiGetClassDevsA(byref(GUID_SPWR_BASE_INTERFACE), None, 0, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE)
 
print(hDevInfo)
 
for index in range(256):
    interfaceData = SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA()
    if not winapi.SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, None, byref(GUID_SPWR_BASE_INTERFACE), index, byref(interfaceData)):
        if GetLastError() != 0:
            raise WinError()
```

and is then throwing the code:

> OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work on 32-bit systems but not x64,
because by default python library converts pointers to 32-bit integers.
So you need redefine function prototypes to explicitly ask python to convert them to 64-bit.

Here is a working example (to be added after SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA definition)

```
SetupDiGetClassDevs = windll.setupapi.SetupDiGetClassDevsA
SetupDiGetClassDevs.argtypes = [POINTER(GUID), c_char_p, c_void_p, wintypes.DWORD]
SetupDiGetClassDevs.restype = c_void_p

SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces = windll.setupapi.SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces
SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, POINTER(GUID), wintypes.DWORD, POINTER(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA)]
SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces.restype = c_int
```